# Error when trying to apply Always Encrypted encryption on aspnet_Membership table

Tags: sql, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt the Email and LoweredEmail columns on a SQL database using Always Encrypted encryption using SSMS and I always get the same error:

> Lock request time out period exceeded. There is no user table matching
> the input name '[dbo].[aspnet_Membership]' in the current database or
> you do not have permission to access the table.

I still get the same error when I log in as the SA account, it's not a permissions problem.
[image: SSMS Wizard 1]

[image: SMS Wizard 2]

[image: SSMS Wizard 3]

[image: SSMS Wizard 4]

[image: SSMS Wizard Error]

Comment: I'm using SQL Management Server wizard to encrypt the column, setting the Encryption Type to Deterministic and generating a new Encryption Key (CEK_Auto1). The SSMS wizard generates the column master key and saves it in the Windows certificate store for the Current User.

Comment: You might get more assistance / visibility by asking this question on the DBA stack exchange site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a work around solution for this;

1. You need to check the tempdb Size and expand the auto growth on both target DB and tempdb.
2. create a job to take periodically the transaction log backup on your target DB.
3. expand the size of mdf and ldf on that DB
4. [Action] urgent make sure to delete any failed encryptions temp tables from old times as every time you fail with this Always Encryption system will generate the tmp_ms_xx_[your_tableName]
5. do a cleanup after all.

Good luck and hope it helps
Regards,
Noori